# Hypothetical question about doing a random sequence of base64 - base85 - Hex encoding/decoding as a method of obfuscation

Tags: bash, encoding, passwords, command-line-interface, decoding

So I know this might not be a secure method of encryption or obfuscation and likely not the recommended way either but I was wondering if it was remotely feasible or practical to encode little secrets on my own private PC by taking a string, like a password for example, and coming up with an encoding sequence using very basic encoding methods using bash scripts.

For example

```bash
echo  Password | base64 | base85 | base64 | hex | base85
PENdTilAbCVZPUByNSgr
```

and then upon pulling that password from my little txt key pair database use the exact opposite decoding sequence to end up back at the original password.

Is this a practical form of obfuscation and does it actually provide any security at all? Its not like I need super good security for storing words on my pc that only I use but this got me thinking.

Comment: Don't do this. Security by obscurity is insecure garbage, and you have other tools like `gpg` or `openssl` available. Base64 et al look characteristically like base64 (or al ;-)  and are easy to reverse.

Comment: How about something like [How can I encrypt / decrypt AES-256 CBC with OpenSSL?](https://superuser.com/a/1361462/754490) or [How to use encrypted and decrypted passwords in shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50462972/6771046)